# PC capable of 64 bit?

Tags: cpu, 64-bit

Here is my system information :

- Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 32-bit
- System Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
- System Model: P55-UD3
- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU         750  @ 2.67GHz (4 CPUs), ~2.7GHz
- Memory: 2048MB RAM
- Available OS Memory: 2040MB RAM

So my question is : Is my PC capable of running 64 bit? If yes, how can I switch to 64 bit?

Comment: The [specifications](http://ark.intel.com/products/42915/Intel-Core-i5-750-Processor-8M-Cache-2_66-GHz) on your i5 750 CPU are very clear with regards to if it supports the 64-bit instruction set.  What part of it's specifications are you not clear on?

Comment: From http://ark.intel.com/products/42915/Intel-Core-i5-750-Processor-8M-Cache-2_66-GHz: Instruction Set: 64-bit.  So yes, it is.  If you install a 64-bit OS anyways.

Comment: Your CPU does support 64-bit.  You will need to acquire and completely reinstall a 64-bit copy of an your operating system.  There is no in-place upgrade path from a 32-bit version of Windows to 64-bit.

Comment: Due to the lack of memory you won't see any performance benefit from running a 64-bit operating system, you actually might see a slight performance decrease, due the low amount of memory you do have and the performance ramifications that comes with a 64-bit operating system.

Comment: If you do upgrade, I'd also upgrade to 8 GB of RAM. It's a cheap and effective improvement for your system.

Comment: thank you for your answers . I'm a bit noob In these things so its normal to ask stupid questions . I'm planning to purchase some memory so I will benefit from switching

Comment: @Johnny.g - You can avoid questions like this by researching the topic.  You don't have to be an expert to look up the specifications of your CPU then look up the requirements for the 64-bit version of Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your PC is capable of running 64-bit operating systems. **All** recent consumer desktop and laptop processors support 64-bit operating systems (if you have an intel i series processor you can count on it, any processor as recent as the first intel i series processors from Intel or AMD will support a 64-bit OS, I don't know of any exceptions unless you're going into different processor architectures like ARM which is used in tiny boards like the raspberry pi, or mobile devices)

However you won't benefit much from it unless there is an application that only runs on a 64-bit version of your operating system because the biggest and most noticeable benefit to running a 64-bit OS is that you can use more than 4GB of RAM in your system. (This can be done in 32-bit operating systems as well but it requires a kernel feature called PAE (Physical Address Extension))

For future reference, practically the only thing that determines whether or not your system supports 64 bit operating systems is your processor architecture (if it's x86/32-bit or older, it doesn't, if it's x86_64/amd64/64-bit then it supports 64 bit operating systems. Pretty simple right?) but of course you also need to be sure that your software has 64-bit compatible drivers (again, most modern or recent hardware will have these drivers)